# Typescript NodeJS in serverless Azure from VSCode

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Is this even supposed to work???

I cannot deploy NodeJS apps as an Azure App Service or an Azure Function App using the MSFT VS Code plugins.

In the former, I get the "Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. Azure Linux web service" even though I'm not using a container -- I'm using NodeJS 16 and "Code."

In a function app, it doesn't look like any of the node dependencies get installed. Does it even run npm install??? And I get errors about missing dependencies (my function app literally only has two dependencies). I can deploy the hello world typescript app from VS Code just fine but the second I try to add literally any dependency to package.json it returns 500s when deployed to azure (but works locally)

Is there some gotcha I'm missing?  I've tried setting PORT and WEBSITES_PORT in the App Service which does nothing.

I'm pretty close to concluding Azure doesn't support NodeJS. I've never had problems with Python or .NET in Azure.

EDIT:

On the function app, I've tried redeploying in a Windows environment which allows me to log into the console via Kudu (unlike on Linux) and manually running npm install as others have directed. The command just hangs forever.

I've trimmed down my packages to nothing but 'node-fetch' in the package.json and the log suggests this package is not installed (for both Linux and Windows deployments) and http requests return 500.

Comment: Could you tell what dependencies you're adding to the `package.json` so that we try to use and check in Azure!

Comment: I did :) See my edit -- even with 'node-fetch' as the only dependency it doesn't work. I also had fast-xml-parser but removed that for testing as it was the dependency referenced in the error message (but it turns out the error message just gets applied to the last imported dependency)